# Why is the output of `typeid(T&).name()` given as `T` instead of `T&`?

Tags: c++, c++11, typeinfo

As the subject, you could check the related code on https://godbolt.org/z/qtjVP6.

For your convience, the code is posted below:

```
#include<typeinfo>
#include<iostream>

class Widget{};

Widget someWidget;

int main()
{
    Widget&& var1 = Widget{};      // here, “&&” means rvalue reference
    auto&& var2 = var1;              // here, “&&” does not mean rvalue reference

    std::cout << typeid(var2).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:`6Widget`

`echo 6Widget | c++filt -t` says `Widget`.

I would be grateful to have some help on this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [C++ Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid#Explanation) (emphasis mine):

> 1) Refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the type type. If type is a reference type, the result refers to a `std::type_info` object representing **the referenced type**.

So for `type = T&`, `typeid(type)` will give results about `T` (reference removed).

It's easy to understand IMO, as for all purposes, a variable of type `T&` is functionally equivalent to one of type `T`.

Comment: If i understand you correctly, for  either `type=T&` or `type=T&&`, `typeid(type)` will give results about `T`. Am i right? If so, one more question raises, how could i distinguish between `T&` and `T&&` by the output of the binary program.

Comment: @sunshilong369 Use [`std::is_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_reference) and its cousins [`std::is_lvalue_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_lvalue_reference) and [`std::is_rvalue_reference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_rvalue_reference).

Comment: @iBug: In `typeid(int)`, `int` is a _`type-id`_, whereas in `int& a; typeid(a)`, `a` is an _id-expression_ ? If you refer to [expr.typeid]p4, the quote you have provided only applies to the form `typeid(type-id)`

Answer (score 2):

Although, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62126051/514514) given by iBug is correct in a way, it doesn't really apply to your case.

Let's look at what C++ standard has to say about this. We can see **[expr]p5** says:

> [5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr#5) If an expression initially has the type “reference to T” ([dcl.ref], [dcl.init.ref]), the type is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis. The expression designates the object or function denoted by the reference, and the expression is an lvalue or an xvalue, depending on the expression.

All this is saying is that in:

```
     std::cout << typeid(var2).name() << std::endl;
```

the type of `var2` is adjusted from `Widget&` to `Widget` before the expression is further evaluated.
Now it's easier to see why `typeid(var2).name()` returns a string corresponding to type `Widget`.

In case, you want to dig deeper, **[expr.typeid]p3** says:

> [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr#3) When typeid is applied to an expression other than a glvalue of a polymorphic class type, the result refers
>   to a std::type_info object representing the static type of the expression. Lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-topointer
>   (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) conversions are not applied to the expression. If the type of the
>   expression is a class type, the class shall be completely-defined. The expression is an unevaluated operand
>   (Clause 5).

Which basically means that `var2` in `typeid(var2)` is a *glvalue* of a non-polymorphic class type and that for an expression of such a type, the type is its static type. The type therefore is `Widget`.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62134074/why-does-typeidx-typeidy-evaluate-to-true-where-x-and-y-are-id-exp) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification.What do you mean by " static type"(Which basically means that var2 in typeid(var2) is a glvalue of a non-polymorphic class type and that for an expression of such a type, the type is its static type. )?Could me explain that in more detail?I'd appreciate that if you could make it clearer by giving some simple examples.

Comment: @sunshilong369 You can understand *static/dynamic type* with following example. Consider this code, `class A {}; class B : A {}; A* a1 = new A; A* a2 = new B;`, the *static type* of both `*a1` and `*a2` here is `A`, however the *dynamic type* of `*a1` is `A` and that of `*a2` is `B`. In a nutshell, dynamic type comes into picture usually during inheritance.