# Why does 'typeid(x) == typeid(y)' evaluate to true, where 'x' and 'y' are id-expression of type T and T& respectively?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, typeid

I am reading the C++11 draft standard and the section on [expr.typeid] mentions the following (emphasis mine):

> [...]
>
> When typeid is applied to an expression other than a glvalue of a polymorphic class type, the result refers
>   to a std::type_info object representing the static type of the expression. Lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-topointer
>   (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) conversions are not applied to the expression. If the type of the
>   expression is a class type, the class shall be completely-defined. The expression is an unevaluated operand
>   (Clause 5).
>
> **When typeid is applied to a *type-id***, the result refers to a std::type_info object representing the type of
>   the type-id. **If the type of the type-id is a reference to a possibly cv-qualified type, the result of the typeid
>   expression refers to a std::type_info object representing the cv-unqualified referenced type.** If the type of
>   the type-id is a class type or a reference to a class type, the class shall be completely-defined.

Further in p5 of the same section, it goes on to give the following example:

```
class D { /* ... */ };
D d1;
const D d2;

typeid(d1) == typeid(d2); // yields true
typeid(D)  == typeid(const D); // yields true
typeid(D)  == typeid(d2); // yields true
typeid(D)  == typeid(const D&); // yields true   -- (1)
```

Given the following code sample:

```
int main()
{
    int foo = 42;
    int &bar = foo;
    bool comp1 = (typeid(int) == typeid(int&));    // Yields true, same as (1)   -- (2) 
    bool comp2 = (typeid(foo) == typeid(bar));     // Yields true, Why?          -- (3)
}
```

My understanding is that **[expr.typeid]p4** talks only about the form **typeid(*type-id*)** and `bar` in `typeid(bar)` is an *id-expression* and not a *type-id*. Why does (3) above evaluate to `true`? Which text in the standard covers this? What have I missed?

Comment: `typeid` doesn't care about constness or references. To `typeid` it's still the same type.

Comment: You have the answer in your question.  *If the type of the type-id is a reference to a possibly cv-qualified type, the result of the typeid expression refers to a std::type_info object representing the cv-unqualified referenced type.* means that you get the typeid of the refered to thing, not the reference itself.

Comment: Note that it says *referenced type.*, not *reference type*.

Comment: @NathanOliver The text says *When typeid is applied to a **type-id***, I am trying to figure out where does it say "When typeid is applied to a glvalue expression...the result refers to a std::type_info object representing the cv-unqualified referenced type"?

Comment: @NathanOliver - That is not the answer to the question. `bar` is *not* a type-id, the paragraph does not apply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in **[expr]**

> [5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr#5) If an expression initially has the type “reference to T” ([dcl.ref],
>   [dcl.init.ref]), the type is adjusted to T prior to any further
>   analysis. The expression designates the object or function denoted by
>   the reference, and the expression is an lvalue or an xvalue, depending
>   on the expression.

So when we get into **[expr.typeid]**

> [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.typeid#3) When typeid is applied to an expression other than a glvalue of a
>   polymorphic class type, the result refers to a std::type_info object
>   representing the static type of the expression. Lvalue-to-rvalue
>   ([conv.lval]), array-to-pointer ([conv.array]), and
>   function-to-pointer ([conv.func]) conversions are not applied to the
>   expression. If the type of the expression is a class type, the class
>   shall be completely-defined. The expression is an unevaluated operand
>   (Clause [expr]).

The id-expression in question is already of the referenced type when `typeid` examines it.

Comment: I might be nitpicking but in `typeid(bar)` isn't `bar` a sub-expression? Where as the text in [expr] talks about expressions.

Comment: @Cheshar - You make an arbitrary distinction. All expressions are subject to the rule, whether or not they are the complete expression or sub-expressions thereof.

Comment: But shouldn't the standard say that explicitly; that all expressions(either full or sub) are subject to this rule? On the other hand, looking at [intro.execution]p10 *A full-expression is an expression that is not a subexpression of another expression. [ Note: in some contexts, such as unevaluated operands, a syntactic subexpression is considered a full-expression (Clause 5). —end note ]* which might explain this specific case, since the operand of typeid is unevaluated for non-polymorphic glvalue types?

Comment: @Cheshar - A full-expression in the sense `[intro.execution]` describes need not be an expression in the sense of `[expr]`. From the very example in the paragraph `S s2 = 2;` is a "full expression", but not an expression under `[expr]`. The wording in the intro deals more with sequencing. The rule I cited deals with all expressions described under `[expr].` In this snippet `int a = 1; int& b = 1; a + b;`, the type of the id-expression `b` is `int`, and it is that type which is used to determine the meaning of the expression as in `[expr.add]` (i.e. if an operand is of arithmetic type).

Comment: In other words, no sub-expression lives in a vacuum. Its type and value category is instrumental in determining the meaning of other expressions composed over it. That is why the rule applies to sub-expressions as well.

Comment: True. *Logically* what you say makes perfect sense and I agree with you as well. But then it's the standard we are interpreting so there isn't any room for assumptions. To say an expression means one thing in one context in the standard and another at a different place has to be backed by the standard itself.

Comment: @Cheshar - We can turn this around. Where in the entirety if `[expr]` is the term "sub-expression" mentioned? The answer is once as far as I can see, and it in no way delineates them as something special. It's not even a normative term there. It's only used for its standard English meaning.

Comment: [expr.const]p2: *A conditional-expression is a core constant expression unless it involves one of the following as a potentially
evaluated **subexpression*** - that's just one example, there are others as well. :) Again, the point is to treat what is written in the standard as definitive.

Comment: @Cheshar - That doesn't disprove my point. It's still used for its standard English meaning. And the standard is not definitive by a long shot. The standard is a document to formally describe a programming language to *people*. It still relies on the reader's grasp of the English language. Not *every* terms requires a precise definition or carries some special meaning beyond its dictionary meaning.

Comment: I also feel that given the ability of every compiler vendor in the past 35 years to understand that `[expr]` really deals with *all* expressions, be they part of a larger one or not, the standard has accomplished its goal with the wording it used.

Answer (score 3):

Much of C++'s expression "system" works this way. You're observing just one example of a rule that's interwoven throughout the language: references sometimes aren't really "things" in the context of an expression; they just refer to an extant object in the same way that its original name of declaration would. They're intended to be "transparent" at some layers, and this is evident in some of the inner workings.

It may seem counter-intuitive in places; for example, though `std::move(expr)` returns a `T&&`, the resulting expression is an rvalue `T` (*not* a `T&&`) … it is the fact that this expression is an rvalue that allows it to bind to rvalue reference parameters when you later pass it to some function. (There is a common misconception that it is the matching type `T&&` that makes this work.)

`typeid` is arguably another counter-intuitive example. The specific rule you're missing is [`[expr.type]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1), responsible for "decaying" these reference types in an expression before any other processing. At that point, the *value category* of the expression takes on important meaning, and this value category is at least partially determined by the original, unadjusted type. This is how the type and value category of expressions evolves as data moves through your program.

*(The subsequent stripping of the `const` is part of [the rules for `typeid`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.typeid#5) that you already quoted.)*

*(The rules for `typeid` when passed a type [are also distinct](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.typeid#4)).*

Usually, we don't have to worry about this. Unfortunately, there are several places where you can observe it that feel a bit like an abstraction leak. You've found one of those places. The rules do make everything come together in the end though.

Comment: There's probably something else to it, in addition to `[expr.type]/1`. It doesn't explain stripping constness, and the fact that reference-ness is ignored even when you pass a type rather than an expression.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat [That's right](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.typeid#5) (the OP already quoted that)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat And, yes, the variant that takes a type [has its own distinct rules](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.typeid#4)